# Bluetooth missing data Android-Arduino

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, processing

So, I created a program that draws a graph in your android device with the data send by the arduino, the problem is that arduino is sending me an an analog signal example: 240,241,240,242 and the android log is reading:2,40,241,240,2,42

I read that it has something to do with sending the data directly to the drawing.

Here is the part of the code that sends the read information:

```html
 public void run() {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer para almacenar el string
      int bytes; // N\u00ba de bytes leidos

      // Escuchamos en el InputStream
      while (true) {
            try {
                // leemos
                bytes = ins.read(buffer);
                // enviamos lo leido al interfaz de usuario
                mHandler.obtainMessage(LEE_MSG, bytes, -1, buffer)
                .sendToTarget();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                break;
            }
      }
  }
```

And here is the code that receives the data:

```html
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() 
{
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what) {
     case ESCRIBE_MSG:
        //No usado en este caso
        break;
     case LEE_MSG:
       //Obtiene los datos desde el msg.obj
       String strRecibido = null;
       byte[] datRecibidos = (byte[]) msg.obj;
       // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
       strRecibido = new String(datRecibidos, 0, msg.arg1);
       if (strRecibido != null) {
         strRecibido=trim(strRecibido);
         float Datos= parseFloat(strRecibido);
```

Could anyone give me the exact code to make the numbers always be as they should? I promise I've been looking forever in the forums and need you.

Thanks

Comment: Problem is, you don't have a protocol. You need some special char to know when one number is complete. Then you can pass that number to handling and listen for the next one. Why don't you send an integer in the first place? You would always know it has same length in bytes.

Comment: I already tried this: in the arduino there is a "," at the end of every analog read, then I use int[] nums = int(split(numbers, ',')); the problem is that it still does the same. It has something to do with the buffer from what I read.

This for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422814/android-bluetooth-communication-with-arduino

Comment: Did you check that the last number was terminated by "," ? If the last char in the received buffer is not equal to ",", the number is not complete. So you have to put it back into the buffer for the next receive-iteration.